# Adding class via query for loader

Tags: jquery

Currently I have a method on an html element that triggers an Ajax call like so:

```
<input value="" id='searchForScanner' onChange="scanOrderNumber(this)" type="text">
```

This method then does the Ajax call.  In this method I added a class to another element.  When this element is added the css loader displays like so:

This displays the spinner when it's loaded:

```
<div class="loadingAjax cssload-whirlpool"></div>
```

class cssload-whirlpool

In my method I attempt to add it like so:

```
function scanOrderNumber(orderId) {
  onClickScanBtn("#scanCompleteBtn", "#scanSearchBtn", "#markOrderComplete");
  //get order area element
  $('.loadingAjax').addClass('cssload-whirlpool');

  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: `api/search-scan`,
  headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $( "#token-auth" ).val(),
    },
  data: { orderNumber: orderId.value },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data, status, xhr){
  console.log(data);
   setOrderDetails(data.orderDate, data.orderNumber, data.customerName);
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, message){
    console.log(status);
  },

  });
}
```

I can visually see the class is there but it doesn't activate the spinner.  Is there anyway I could activate it?

Comment: Are you sure that the spinner would start working just by providing that cssload-whirlpool class?? Or maybe there has to be some .trigger() function to be called

Comment: Is it a @keyframe animation or something else?

Answer (score 0):

you can hide and show the button

```
<div class="loadingAjax cssload-whirlpool" style="display:none;"></div>
```

in ajax call

```
function scanOrderNumber(orderId){
   $('.loadingAjax ').show();
   $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     ...
     success : function(){
       $('.loadingAjax ').hide();
    }
   })
}
```

Comment: The objective is not about show/hide the element. The problem is that an added class should do a spinner animation and doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To Adding class via a query for the loader.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p:first").addClass("intro");
  });
});
</script>
<style>
.intro {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Add a class name to the first p element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is not about adding the class. OP said *"I can visually see the class is there but it doesn't activate the spinner."*